# Empty gray space is coming when svg is placed over document using sticky position along with bottom property

Tags: css, css-selectors, styles

I am displaying a pdf document in my web application. There is a requirement to draw shapes over document. So we have used svg to draw shapes over document.
We are using below css to place it over document.

```
.svgPos {
  cursor: crosshair:
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 500px;
}
```

------- Code

```
<div height="700" >
<pdfviewer height="1800" />
<svg className="svgPos" height="1800" />
</div>
```

On applying this css we are able to draw shapes over document, but empty gray space is coming below the document of 500 px.
Svg and pdf viewer are scrollable.
Can anyone let me know how can I fix this?

Comment: It's going to be difficult to answer this without seeing more code. What does your HTML structure look like?

Comment: Added html inside my component

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the `position: sticky` is needed in your CSS.

You could try wrapping both the pdf viewer and the svg in a relative div. Then you could give the svg an absolute position over the top of the pdf viewer.

The current code you gave shows a div already wrapping both the pdfviewer and svg, so you could use that as the wrap.

For example:

```css
.wrap {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
pdfviewer {
  height: 1800px;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <pdfviewer></pdfviewer>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="1800">
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="50" stroke="#000"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```